# Spring boot jpa not printing sql logs

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, log4j2

I am trying to print the sql statements in log file but it is not working.

Below is application-property file:

```
custom.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/custom_service?useSSL=false
custom.datasource.username=root
custom.datasource.password=paytm@123
custom.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
custom.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
custom.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=none
##show sql statement
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql=trace
```

Log4j root level is set to debug mode. What is wrong here?

Log4j Config as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<DynamicThresholdFilter key="x-debug-enabled" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="NEUTRAL">
    <KeyValuePair key="true" value="DEBUG"/>
</DynamicThresholdFilter>

<Appenders>
    <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="[%level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} requestId: %X{requestId}, customerId: %X{customerId} - %msg%n"></PatternLayout>
    </Console>
    <File name="File" fileName="/var/log/custom-onboarding-service/custom-onboarding-service.log" ignoreExceptions="false">
        <PatternLayout pattern="[%level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} requestId: %X{requestId}, customerId: %X{customerId} - %msg%n"></PatternLayout>
    </File>
    <File name="FileException" fileName="/var/log/custom-onboarding-service/custom-onboarding-service-error.log" ignoreExceptions="false">
        <PatternLayout pattern="[%level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} requestId: %X{requestId}, customerId: %X{customerId} - %msg%n"></PatternLayout>
    </File>
    <RollingFile name="customOnboarding" fileName="/var/log/custom-onboarding-service/custom-onboarding-service-audit.log"
                 filePattern="/var/log/custom-onboarding-service/custom-onboarding-service-audit-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
        <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>%m%n</Pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="250 MB"/>
        </Policies>
    </RollingFile>
</Appenders>

<Loggers>
    <Root level="debug">
        <AppenderRef ref="FileException" level="ERROR"></AppenderRef>
    </Root>
    <Logger name="com.nv.custom" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="File" />
        <AppenderRef ref="FileException" level="ERROR"></AppenderRef>
    </Logger>
    <Logger name="JSON_LOGGER" level="info" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="customOnboarding" />
    </Logger>
</Loggers>
```

Below is the custom DB Config File used to configure the spring JPA Configs:

**Custom DB Config File:**

```
 @PersistenceContext(unitName = "custom")
@Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
        @Qualifier("customDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
    factoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("custom");
    factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
    factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.nv.custom.db.mktcustom.entities","com.nv.custom.onboarding.entity");
    Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getRequiredProperty("custom.hibernate.dialect"));
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getRequiredProperty("custom.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
    jpaProperties.put("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql", env.getRequiredProperty("custom.hibernate.show_sql"));
    jpaProperties.put("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql", env.getRequiredProperty("custom.hibernate.format_sql"));
    factoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);
    return factoryBean;
}
```

Comment: You are using Log4j2 instead of Logback, right? How did you configure Log4j2

Comment: @SimonMartinelli  added the log4j2 config..

Comment: Try adding the org.hibernate loggers also to the Log4j2.xml

Answer (score 2):

To show sql query in spring-boot u need to set below properties.

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

you using custom properties for db configuration. then add required properties in your custom configuration method.

```
    custom.hibernate.show_sql=true
    custom.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

Configuration for above two properties:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "custom")
@Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
        @Qualifier("customDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
    factoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("custom");
    factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
    factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.nv.custom.db.mktcustom.entities","com.nv.custom.onboarding.entity");
    Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getRequiredProperty("custom.hibernate.dialect"));
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getRequiredProperty("custom.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.format_sql", env.getRequiredProperty("custom.hibernate.show_sql"));
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", env.getRequiredProperty("custom.hibernate.format_sql"));
    factoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);
    return factoryBean;
}
```

Comment: Check ur cofiguration method also. I said

Comment: I have the custom config in question. can you please check.

Comment: "To show sql query in spring-boot u need to set below properties" no that's just one way. The other is to use the loggers in the question

Comment: @NishantVarshney i added configuration

Comment: I have tried this config.. but doesn't seems working... by adding the hibernate logger it is printing all the hibernate logs...

Answer (score 2):

In your configuration you have the root logging level as debug. But then you set the level on the FileException Appender to error, so only errors are going to be logged to that file and you have no other Appenders configured for the root logger.

If you want to print logs from Hibernate add a Logger such as

```
<Logger name="org.hibernate" level="debug" additivity="false">
  <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
</Logger>
```

Comment: It is printing the hibernate logs but didn't printing the actual JPA query...

Answer (score 1):

Please configure the below in the log4j2.xml

```
    <RollingFile fileName="${LOG-DIR}/SQL.log" filePattern="${LOG-DIR}/${SQL-LOG-ROLLING-FILE-NAME}" name="APPENDER1">
        <LevelRangeFilter maxLevel="TRACE" minLevel="DEBUG" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
        <PatternLayout pattern="${APP-LOG-PATTERN}"/>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="2 GB"/>
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="100"/>
    </RollingFile>
</Appenders>


    <logger additivity="false" level="DEBUG" name="org.hibernate.SQL">
        <appender-ref ref="APPENDER1"/>
    </logger>
    
    <Root level="INFO">
        <AppenderRef ref="OTHER_APPENDER"/> 
    </Root>
```